# MoveByOffset does not work in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a canvas and there i need to move the mouse from one point to another point to draw a rectangle. CapabilityType.HasNativeEvents is set to false. I'm using IE11 and .Net. The issue is while using selenium grid in continuous integration machine but works fine in local .

I tried this but it does not work. Any clue?

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(_webDriver);
        builder.MoveToElement(Canvas, 800, 250).Click().Build().Perform();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        builder.ClickAndHold(Canvas).MoveByOffset(500, -30).Build().Perform();
```